# Sharepoint 2013: List and List Form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, custom-form, list-form

I have a few fields that I would like to add to my custom list forms. I do not want the values of these fields to be displayed in any columns on the list. How can I add these fields, mainly text boxes, to the form. And I will need to be able to view/edit the data entered in one form in the other forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways I can think of to handle this, based on what I think you described.

1. Created your fields - and then just create a custom list view that doesn't show those column.  Your fields will be visible in the edit form.
2. Use InfoPath - with InfoPath you can have fields tied to XML that never populate in the list (this if for InfoPath library forms, not InfoPath List form - there is a difference).
3. Use custom form and modify the XSLT see this [Hide fields on sharepoint custom list form, No code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37840/hide-fields-on-sharepoint-custom-list-form-no-code)